# Sinatra, DRY and scoping

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm looking for ways to DRY my Sinatra app and have run into some scoping issues -- in particular, helpers and Sinatra functions are not available inside my handlers. Can someone please tell me if there's a way to fix this code and more importantly, what is going on?

Thank you.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'pp'

helpers do
  def h(txt)
    "<h1>#{txt}</h1>"
  end
end

before do
  puts request.path
end


def r(url, get_handler, post_handler = nil)
  get(url){ get_handler.call } if get_handler
  post(url){ post_handler.call } if post_handler
end


routes_composite_hash = {
    '/' => lambda{ h('index page'); pp params }, #can't access h nor params!!!
    '/login' => [lambda{'login page'}, lambda{'login processing'}],
    '/postonly' => [nil, lambda{'postonly processing'}],
}

routes_composite_hash.each_pair do |k,v|
  r(k, *v)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting!

Do this:

```
def r(url, get_handler, post_handler = nil) 
  get(url, &get_handler) if get_handler
  post(url, &post_handler) if post_handler
end


routes_composite_hash = {
    '/' => lambda{ h('index page'); pp params },
    '/login' => [lambda{'login page'}, lambda{'login processing'}],
    '/postonly' => [nil, lambda{'postonly processing'}],
}

routes_composite_hash.each_pair do |k,v|
  r(k, *v)
end
```

As [Kashyap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/465082/kashyap) explains, you were calling your get and post handlers inside the `main` context. This just converts sent lambda to a block and passes it to the desired method.

Comment: Ah very good, I didn't realise you could pass the block directly to get/post! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

The methods you define inside `helpers do .. end` blocks are available only inside routes and filters and views contexts and thus, since you are not using them inside any of those, it won't work. Lambdas preserve the execution context which means that in the hash `{'/' => lambda { h }..}`, the context is `main` but inside the `get` method, the context changes and the helpers are available only in this context.

To achieve what you want to do though, (although I would suggest you avoid doing this), you can just define the helpers as lambdas inside your app file itself. In your case, it would be:

```
def h(txt) 
  "<h1>#{txt}</h1>"
end

# And then the rest of the methods and the routes hash
```

This way, the `h` method is in the context of the `main` object and thus will be visible all over.

Comment: There must be a way to eval a block in a specified context but I was unable to do it.